# How to rearrange code alphabetically in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, code-formatting

As I understand, built-in rearranger sort members of the class by access, final and static modifiers, but not alphabetically. Recommended for this plugin rearranger is definitely outdated (last update in November 2011)

Please recommend me something for Android Studio with functionality like plugin Codemaid in Visual Studio or just sorting with an alphabet.

Thanks for the consideration!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On a Mac (Android Studio 3.2.1)

Go to preferences -> Plugins -> Browse Repositories

Search for Lines Sorter.  Install the plugin.

Once installed restart Android Studio, go to Edit -> Sort Lines (Last Option) after making a selection.

Installed Plugin Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Awesome! On Windows (Android 3.4): `File > Settings... > Plugins`.